# Send Batch events to Event Hub using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am able to send events to Event Hub as a batch using the Nuget package [Azure.Messaging.EventHubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send).But I want to use REST API.
I am able to [send single events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-event) to Event Hub using REST API using Postman. But as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-batch-events) if I need to send batch events in REST API I need add header `Content-Type:application/vnd.microsoft.servicebus.json` and Also the message should be enclosed with the "Body"
like `[{"Body":"Message1"},{"Body":"Message2"},{"Body":"Message3"}]`

So if I need to send json as event then should I create a json string and send it?

Sample:

```
   [
   {
      "Body":"{\"ID\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"abc1\"}"
   },
   {
      "Body":"{\"ID\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"def1\"}"
   },
   {
      "Body":"{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"xyz1\"}"
   }
   ]
```

OR is there any other option to send event as Batch using the REST API to Event Hub.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to send a batch of messages via REST as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Body" is a string content then yes, you must escape your JSON content first. Your sample looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create an events list -

```
List<Event> events = new List<Event>(){
    new Event(1,"abc1"),
    new Event(2,"def1"),
    new Event(3,"xyz1"),
}
```

and send it via POST